# Getting images rotated when showing images from IPhone in slider layout

Tags: android, slider

Hello i am using slider library i.e com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
to show images in slide. Now this works fine and everything looks great but when i show images from iphone it rotates them. I tried finding a solution but no luck so posting question here. This is my code.

```
private void setSlider() {
    mImagesSlider.removeAllSliders();
    for (String name : mDeal.getImages()) {
        DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getActivity());
        defaultSliderView
                .image(URLConstant.IMAGE_URL + name)  //Image URL
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

        //add your extra information
        defaultSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        defaultSliderView.getBundle()
                .putString("extra", name);

        mImagesSlider.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
    }

    mImagesSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

I am using DefaultSliderView because i didn't need the description. Help will be really appreciated , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. So if someone stumbles on this problem. Here's what i did. I followed [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Slider-view) like and made custom slider view. At the end i removed the bindEventAndShow(v, target) line. And set the image using glide and it worked perfectly.